# Printout for receipt printer

Tags: python, printing, wxpython, receipt

I have prepared a small program for retail shop, and have to print out receipt (using tvs msp star 240 dot matrix printer/with paper roll) .
with wx.Printout() class for printing , as print preview is ok but actual printing is different and awkward :
1. i m using paper roll n don't know how to call end printing/OnEndPrinting()/ cut paper  ?
2. how to correct text shape or which font for actual printout ?
I m new for programming .....
Please help and suggest appropriate code for this ...
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figure out some sort of solution :
receipt printing is impossible with wxPython , so, raw printing with escape sequences would be better option
os.system("echo ' some text ' | lpr -o raw" )
first initialize printer
os.system("echo ' \x1B\x40' | lpr -o raw" )
for bold letters with ESC code :
os.system("echo ' \x1BE some text \x1BF ' | lpr -o raw" )
for double width :
os.system("echo ' \x1BW\01 some text ' | lpr -o raw" )
for underline
os.system("echo ' \x1B\035 some text \x1B\034' | lpr -o raw" )
and many more options can be used with ESC code